# Tool for JSON API Documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, documentation, cucumber

Is there a tool or an easy way to generate/maintain documentation of a rich RESTful JSON API?

I also would want to publish and maintain (as executable documentation) it, something like what [relishapp](https://www.relishapp.com) provides. [An example](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/method-stubs/stub-with-a-simple-return-value).

The application is Restful Ruby on Rails 3 application, tested using cucumber and R-Spec controller tests.

Comment: Why not just use [rdoc](http://rdoc.rubyforge.org/) or something of that family?  It turns your source-code's comments into an api browser.

Comment: Thanks, thats good. But I wanted something more like cucumber which you constantly run (red/green) and just be maintained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you have Cucumber tests already - they *are* your documentation. They may just need some work to be readable.

For output, you can use Cucumber's built-in HTML formatter.

Comment: Yeah sure, I do that in most cases, but I am looking for something more suited for a JSON API, which will help a developer use the JSON API in a better way. With all the request response, params etc but not having to make it very verbose with cucumber.